# Apt pinning based by url

Tags: apt, apt-cache, pinning

I want to have in avaiable sources two repos:

- https://qgis.org/ubuntu
- https://qgis.org/ubuntugis

Is there way to pin first one with priority 600 ans second one with 450?

Maybe I can add some option to sources.list?

I already tried :

1. to pin by origin and version but with no luck
2. add ip with new hostname to `/etc/hosts` to change origin but get http 409 error

Packages from second one have `-ubuntugis` in version.

Comment: This is going to be hard to do and maybe impossible to pin. `apt-cache policy | grep -A2 //qgis` shows the parameters that you can pin for "release" and "origin". As you can see, all of the "release" parameters are the same and "origin" is also the same. As for setting the version, [only trailing wildcards are supported](https://wiki.debian.org/AptConfiguration#line-138).

Comment: I need the same and could not find a solution. I am just very surprised that there is no mechanism for matching the path part of a repository URL. A workaround is to host the repositories using differing subdomains, then utilize the `origin` matcher.